# Disk partitioning issue not using full SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm using a 250gb internal SSD for Ubuntu (dual boot, windows on a separate SSD) but I must of messed up the partitioning when installing Ubuntu. Only 28gb is being used for the root and another 165gb is not being used. When I mount and view it through files, it just shows the default /home setup (desktop,documents,downloads ..etc). Is there some way I can use this space without having to reinstall Ubuntu?
Here are relevant snippets:

**>lsblk**

```
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  29.8G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 165.8G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda5   8:5    0  27.4G  0 part /
```

**>fdisk /dev/sda**

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   58593280 121094143  62500864  29.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  121094144 468860927 347766784 165.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4       4096   1054719   1050624   513M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5    1054720  58593279  57538560  27.4G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Did you partition in advance? It looks like you have newer gpt partitioning, but old BIOS boot install since you have sda1 as BIOS boot. Also new installs do not create swap but will use one if you already have it. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Partition for / is in wrong spot to resize the /, perfect spot if you want separate /home though. My / only uses 8.5GB so you should be good with that for /.

```
root@zeus-H370M:~# df -h | grep sda2
/dev/sda2       110G  8.5G   96G   9% /
```

If you want you can just copy your /home directory to the spare partition. The steps to do it are boot with your install disk in Try it first mode then open the Terminal program.

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3
sudo mkdir /tmp/newhome
sudo mkdir /tmp/oldhome
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /tmp/newhome
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /tmp/oldhome
sudo cp -Rp /tmp/oldhome/home/user_name /tmp/newhome/
sudo rm -r /tmp/oldhome/home/user_name
sudo nano /tmp/oldhome/etc/fstab
```

Add the lines.

```
# Added by me for separate /home partition due to the partitioning done to use most of my space.
/dev/sda3 /home ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Reboot and you will have your home directory now on the newly used partition.